# how i can intent from notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

Why is `Intent` from notification null?

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, myclass.class);
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        Bundle extras=new Bundle();
        extras.putString("key","value");
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
            NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("test")
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setSound(sound)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setExtras(extras)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService((context.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
            notificationManager.notify(0, n.build());
    }
```

but in `onStart()` of myclass when i call `getintent().getExtras()` the result is **null**, why?
how can I  `getExtras()` from notification Intent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think u forgot to call.

```
resultIntent.putExtras(extras);
```

before calling it.

Comment: ok but then what is it .setExtras(extras) in NotificationCompat.Builder and how to get it?

Comment: actually i never used that .. but i sent data in notification with just like the way i said.. is it working ?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, you can get idea from it:

```
 Intent notificationClickIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationAppListing.class);
            notificationClickIntent.putExtra("notificationType", notificationTypeOne);
            notificationClickIntent.putExtra("notificationUrl", notificationUrl);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Search.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationClickIntent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(mId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add your extras to your `resultIntent`, not `NotificationCompat.Builder` (and not `resultPendingIntent`)

```
Bundle extras=new Bundle();
extras.putString("key","value");
resultIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

or simply:

```
resultIntent.putExtra("key","value");
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to place

```
resultIntent.putExtras(bundle)
```

right after bundle is assigned with key value pair

then you can get the values

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String yourValue = extras.getString("key");    
}
```